# Unresolved symbols building a code composer 3 project in code composer 4

Tags: programming, ezdsp, ti-ccstudio

I downloaded a program from texas instruments, PMSM3-2, which is made for code composer studio 3. I only have code composer 4, when attempting to build it I get the errors:

```
'Building target: C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/build/pmsm3_2.out'
'Invoking: Linker'
"C:/Program Files/Texas Instruments/ccsv4/tools/compiler/c2000/bin/cl2000" -@ccsLinker.opt -o "C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/build/pmsm3_2.out"

 undefined                   first referenced                                              
  symbol                         in file                                                   
 ---------                   ----------------                                              
 _DLOG_4CH_init              C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _DLOG_4CH_update            C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _F281X_EV1_DRIVE_Init       C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _F281X_EV1_DRIVE_Update     C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _F281X_EV1_PWM_Init         C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _F281X_EV1_PWM_Update       C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _F281X_EV1_QEP_Calc         C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _F281X_EV1_QEP_Init         C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _F281X_EV1_QEP_Isr          C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _F281X_EV2_PWMDAC_Init      C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _F281X_EV2_PWMDAC_Update    C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _F281X_ileg2_dcbus_drv_init C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _F281X_ileg2_dcbus_drv_read C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _clarke_calc                C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _ipark_calc                 C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _park_calc                  C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _phase_voltage_calc         C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _pid_reg3_calc              C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _rampgen_calc               C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _rmp_cntl_calc              C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _speed_est_calc             C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _speed_frq_calc             C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _speed_prd_calc             C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj
 _svgendq_calc               C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/obj/pmsm3_2.obj

error: unresolved symbols remain
error: errors encountered during linking;
   "C:/tidcs/DMC/c28/v32x/sys/PMSM3_2_281x/cIQmath/build/pmsm3_2.out" not
   built

>> Compilation failure
```

Is there something I need to change to make it work with ccs4?

Comment: I really hate Code Composer. Sorry you have to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a device-specific library you have to include that defines the I/O devices as they are on your cpu, and another library that supplies the 'IQ math' routines. I don't have access to the CCSv3/ezDSP setup I worked with a year or two ago (long weekend!), but I think at least the IQ math library was IQmath.lib, or possibly IQmath.out; the F2808 in that project required including a file with a name something like ml28xx.out. Sorry I can't get these file names right until probably Monday evening, but if you search for ml28* and/or IQmath* in the C:\tidcs tree, you might be able to find them.

On CCSv3, there was a dialog for compiler/linker options where you could name these libraries as part of your project. Not sure where these would be with the new Eclipse based CCSv4. Perhaps the eclipse way of right clicking the project name, and looking for 'build properties' would reveal the dialog you need.